# Some UTF-8 chars dim when used as text on a button

Tags: android, user-interface, button, utf-8

I need two buttons with triangles ("right" and  "left") in my Android/java application.
Unfortunately the best UTF-8 chars I have found for this purpose are displayed dim - not fully white - " ◀ " and " ▶ ". The problem occurs on my Samsung Galaxy S5, Android 5. It does not occur on any (arm) emulator I was able to run from Android Studio, and it also works ok on a Samsung tablet: Galaxy Note 8.
Please tell if there is something I could do in application code so that the arrow two buttons have correct bright white color for "triangle"-arrows on Samsung Galaxy S5. I already tried android:typeface="normal" and "sans","serif", "monospace" and making text "bold" with no effect. I suppose that if the mentioned characters are displayed incorrectly on SGS5 then it might be the case also in other Android devices. Unfortunately I am not allowed to post image on this site.

activity_main.xml:

```
<Button
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text=" &#x25C0; "
android:paddingLeft="10px"
android:paddingRight="10px"
android:minWidth="0dp"
android:id="@+id/button6" />

<Button
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text=" &#x25B6; "
android:paddingLeft="10px"
android:paddingRight="10px"
android:minWidth="0dp"
android:id="@+id/button7" />
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.solarix.testarrowbutton"
    >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo"
        >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: did you try add 
android:textColor ="#ffffff" ?

Comment: I have just tried your suggestion: android:textColor ="#ffffff" and it does not help. Note that the problem exists only for some Utf-8 chars, not for "normal" letter. Buttons with typical letters are displayed correctly - text is bright white. Only this "arrows/triangles" are dim and only on Galaxy S5 as I have tested so far.